# Limit calls to Facebook graph_url_engagement_count

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-graph-api

I am getting this error, "(#613) Calls to graph_url_engagement_count have exceeded the rate of 10 calls per 3600 seconds." so I want to keep the calls to the API within the limit for a given link.

Note: That the limit of 10 calls per hour only applies to each link.

This is the function I am using:

```
const getFacebookStats = async (link) => {
  try {
    const resp = await axios.get(
      `https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/?id=${link}&fields=engagement&access_token=${BEARER_TOKEN_FACEBOOK}`
    );
    return resp.data.engagement;
  } catch (err) {
    // Handle Error Here
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: So make less requests then ...?

Comment: Your reply makes me realize that I probably should've given more details lol but anyways it's all good now. Solved the problem using LRU cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem using LRU cache.

```
cache.set(link, cache.get(link) == undefined ? 1 : cache.get(link) + 1);
```

Everytime the link was passed onto the getFacebookStats function, the link and its count were stored in the LRU cache, if the same link was being called multiple times then its count got incremented.

In the settings of LRU cache, maxAge was set to 1 hour:

```
maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60,
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I like the idea of the LRU cache, but the rate is not per url, but the total number of requests, so you'd need a global counter.